# Clase dinámica en función del observable Data en Angular

Tags: angular, angular10, angular-router

En mi aplicación tengo un mismo header que cambia de color según la página (modo oscuro o modo claro). Mi idea es añadir una clase dinámica gestionada por un atributo en el router de Angular. Por ejemplo:

```
{ path: 'contact-us', component: ContactComponent, data: { lightNavBar: true } }
```

Así podré dinamizar la clase en el html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" [ngClass]="lightNavBar ? 'nav-white' : 'nav-black'" role="navigation">
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo obtener el valor de `lightNavBar` en mi componente?

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  lightNavBar: boolean = false;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe(res => console.log(res.lightNavBar)); // undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, `data` es un observable que contiene los datos, así que deberías de *subscribirte* a él para obtener el valor, no puedes usarlo como objeto normal. Para estos casos, te recomiendo mirar la [documentación](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#data) donde efectivamente confirman que `data` es un observable :)

Comment: Gracias @Benito-B, también traté de hacerlo bajo suscipción y obtengo `undefined`, por eso traté de hacerlo de diversas maneras, pero no consigo obtener dicho valor. He editado la pregunta donde puedes ver el `subscribe`.

Comment: Prueba a poner esto directamente: `this.route.data.subscribe(res => console.log(res));`, sin intentar acceder a nada, solo para ver *qué* te trae

Comment: Me devuelve un objeto vacío...

Comment: El valor no lo puedes obtener debido a que lo estas mandando al ContactComponent, el data: { lightNavBar: true }  debería estar en la ruta donde se encuentre el HeaderComponent.

Comment: ¿Entonces cómo podría gestionar el cambio de clases según la página?